# Mvc mvvm и еще 10 символов

Tags: javascript, mvvm, mvc

Допустим, есть задача: визуализировать результаты рекурсивной функции(qsort) в виде бинарного дерева. Можно рисовать сразу, прям во время работы - просто запутаться. Можно сначала программно построить модель дерева, а после ее отрисовать - это удобнее.

Как уложить вторую идею в рамки одного из паттернов mvc mvvm? Отрисовка посредством канвас или свг(raphael).

Сам код, который будет строить "модель" можно назвать контроллером?

[Картинка](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/MVC-Process.png/200px-MVC-Process.png) с вики показывает стрелочками, что модель может обращаться к представлению, а [картиночка](http://design-pattern.ru/i/mvc.png), позаимствованная у фаулера - нет. Частью чего должны быть функции отрисовки? Модели или представления?

Чем будет являться представление? Набором функций, осуществляющих отрисовку?

Биндинг модели означает, что при изменении модели будет автоматически вызываться функция отрисовки?

Answer (score 1):

> Частью чего должны быть функции отрисовки? Модели или представления?

Функции отрисовки - представление

> Чем будет являться представление?
> Набором функций осуществляющих
> отрисовку?

Примерно так

> Биндинг модели означает, что при
> изменение модели, будет автоматически
> вызываться функция отрисовки?

Да, но возможно, требуется не полная перерисовка. Это еще зависит от ее тяжести, подумайте как лучше.